# Converting pb to tflite and getting valueerror

Tags: python, tensor, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to convert my pb to tflite using this code. I got the code from github ([ImageCaptioning](https://github.com/fringedroid/ImageCaptioningAndroid/commit/4c3444cb95045e6500c42bbb940567b8f174863c)). The authors made use of this code to convert their model, and I was able to make the pb model, but encountered some issues while trying to convert the pb model to tflite.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile
import cv2
import numpy as np


def main():
    sess = tf.Session()
    GRAPH_LOCATION = 'C:/Users/User/Documents/models-master/research/im2txt/im2txt/data/output_graph.pb'
    VOCAB_FILE = 'C:/Users/User/Documents/models-master/research/im2txt/Pretrained-Show-and-Tell-model-master/word_counts.txt'
    IMAGE_FILE = 'C:/Users/User/Documents/models-master/research/im2txt/g3doc/COCO_val2014_000000224477.jpg'

    # Read model
    with gfile.FastGFile(GRAPH_LOCATION, 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        sess.graph.as_default()
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)

    with tf.gfile.GFile(IMAGE_FILE, "rb") as f:
        encoded_image = f.read()

    input_names = ['import/image_feed:0', 'import/input_feed:0', 'import/lstm/state_feed:0']
    output_names = ['import/softmax:0', 'import/lstm/state:0', 'import/lstm/initial_state:0']

    g = tf.get_default_graph()
    input_tensors = [g.get_tensor_by_name(x) for x in input_names]  
    output_tensors = [g.get_tensor_by_name(x) for x in output_names]


    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_session(sess, input_tensors, output_tensors)
    model = converter.convert()
    fid = open("C:/Users/User/Documents/models-master/research/im2txt/im2txt/data/converted_model.tflite", "wb")
    fid.write(model)
    fid.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but I am getting this error:

```
   "'{0}'.".format(_get_tensor_name(tensor)))
ValueError: Provide an input shape for input array 'import/image_feed'.
```

I am new to tfLite and I am unable to find the issue pertaining to the code.

Answer (score 0):

Root-cause of the error is `input_shape` of input array. You need to provide input shape to the converter. You could inspect *.pb file using [tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard) or [netron](https://lutzroeder.github.io/netron/) to find `input_shapes`. Check an example as follows.

```
import tensorflow as tf
graph_def_file = "./Mymodel.pb"
tflite_file = 'mytflite.tflite'

input_arrays = ["input"]
output_arrays = ["output"]

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(
   graph_def_file=graph_def_file,
   input_arrays=input_arrays,
   output_arrays=output_arrays,input_shapes={'input_mel':[ 1, 32, 32]})

tflite_model = converter.convert()

open(tflite_file,'wb').write(tflite_model)

interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_content=tflite_model)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
```